# mui TextField label width problem, when I do font override

Tags: typescript, material-ui

If I override the label font, the label width is not recalculated, and the outline is in the text.

I prepared [a codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-dust-kidu2?file=/src/App.tsx)

Comment: one simple solution is to add `backdoundColor:"#fff"` to the label. It'll hide the outline.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dynamic label width textfield outlined material ui react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57458833/dynamic-label-width-textfield-outlined-material-ui-react)

Comment: I added backgroundColor to the codesandbox example. It doesn't work. The " dynamic label width textfield outlined material ui react" can be good, if the label text changes. This is not the case this time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got answer on github.

> In your case, you need to customize the font size of the label and the
> gap.

```
"& .MuiInputLabel-root, fieldset": {
  fontSize: "1.1rem",
}
```